# Select box-shape grid between two positions on tilemap

Tags: unity, 2d, mathematics, tilemap, grid

I want to be able to click and hold on a certain point and mark it as `startPosition`.
Then, while the mouse is held down and moved, mark that second position as `endPosition`.

When the mouse is finally released, I want to get all the positions between those two points.

Here is my code so far:

```
for (float x = startPosition.x; x <= endPosition.x; x++)
        {
            for (float y = startPosition.y; y <= endPosition.y; y++)
            {
                Vector3Int newPosition = Utilities.GridPosFromWorldPos(new Vector2(x, y));
                if (!selectedPositions.Contains(newPosition)) { selectedPositions.Add(newPosition); }
            }
        }
```

This works only when dragging up and/or to the right.
As soon as I try to go to left or bottom, the `endPosition` coordinates become smaller than the `startPosition` coordinates, which breaks the for loop.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved like this:

```
        Vector3 lowerLeftTile = new Vector3(Mathf.Min(startPosition.x, endPosition.x), Mathf.Min(startPosition.y, endPosition.y));
        Vector3 upperRightTile = new Vector3(Mathf.Max(startPosition.x, endPosition.x), Mathf.Max(startPosition.y, endPosition.y));

        for (float x = lowerLeftTile.x; x <= upperRightTile.x; x++)
        {
            for (float y = lowerLeftTile.y; y <= upperRightTile.y; y++)
            {
                Vector3Int newPosition = Utilities.GridPosFromWorldPos(new Vector2(x, y));
                if (!selectedPositions.Contains(newPosition)) { selectedPositions.Add(newPosition); }
            }
        }
```